# Best practices for updating SharePoint 2010 production site

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I've a VM (#1) with installed SP 2010 and SQL Server 2008. It suites our needs in terms of load and capacity. In case of breaking down we can revert it to the snapshot.

The development process still goes on. 
The question is what is good approach for updating the production VM?

**Variant 1:**

1. Have a copy of production VM (#2)
2. When the iteration is finished (development->testing->fixing) and we ready to make update we swap the VMs (#1 <--> #2)
3. Testing VM #2 becomes production and #1 becomes testing one.

**" + "** :  We go live with fully tested solution.

**" - "** : Mechanism for sync up between VMs is required.

**Variant 2:**

1. Develop, test and fix on the production VM
2. Publish changes when we are ready.

**" + "** : We don't need mechanism for sync up between VMs

**" - "** : Crashes can happen more often.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on "what" you are developing:

1. Content only

   - It is often easier to do this on the production machine. The standard publishing framework should be sufficent to hide changes from standard users.
   - Or you could use the content deployment features of sharepoint to move it from the dev farm to the production farm
   - Or you could use the content deployment tool
2. Webparts, simple components

   - In 2010, these should be done as sandboxed solutions (if you can get away with it), then they are very simple to upload/change on your prod environment. Build on your dev enironment, then upload through the sharepoint webpages.
3. Complex components

   - Things that require a farm administrator to install on the server (jobs, complex web parts, etc), should be developed with visual studio on your dev box, then moved to prod in a fully tested way. Try having a testing/stage environment.
4. A combination of all of the above

   - This usually depends on how much risk your client is willing to expose themselves to, say for instance, if it is a brand new server there is not much risk in taking down users of the system.

I would **not recommend** installing visual studio on a **PRODUCTION** SharePoint server

Comment: You definitely should not install VS on a production machine.  Far too easy to debug projects which would halt other user's SharePoint accesses.

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT do your development on the production VM. SharePoint is very easy to break during development and you will more than likely bring down your production environment at some point. The risk is basically too high.

Do your development on a separate system. Package your solution/changes properly as a WSP - test it on another system (in between your dev environment, and basically a copy of production). Once it passes all testing on your staging server, deploy the WSP to production.

Swapping systems is a pain in the arse when it comes to SharePoint - you have Alternate Access Mappings, IIS Bindings etc. to worry about - and takes more time and effort than simply just uploading a new WSP and hitting "deploy" (obviously, after testing on your stating server).